# Jquery Show contextmenu on element focus

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I currently have a page in calendar format, where I right click on to show a contextMenu using JQuery. It is working as intended.

I have a scenario where I need to show the contextMenu when user tabs through the elements. I'm trying to show the context menu in onFocus of element with the following code.

**Code that isn't working for `onFocus`:**

```
$("a").focus(function (e) {
    // below for anchor element finding the parent which is "li" element with specific class name
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest('.someclass');
    if (parent.length > 0) {
        //debugger;
        $(".someclass").enableContextMenu(true); // this is not working
    }
    //return false;
});
```

**Working code for mouse right-click**

```
$(".someclass").contextMenu( {
            menu: "notOpenedTasks"
            //, leftButton: true
        },
        function (action, el, pos) {
            contextMenuWork(action, el, pos);
        }
).enableContextMenu();
```

Please let me know if this isn't possible or what I am doing wrong.

P.S: I thnk I dnt xplain clearly srry for that:
Im using jquery.contextMenu.js file to show context menu when user right click an element.
Contextmenu defined like below

    'ul id="notOpenedTasks" class="contextMenu" style="display:none;"'
    -li class="Information">Information
    -li class="Justification">Justification
    -li class="Document">Document
     -/ul
    
and I have "li" element defined like this

... so what it does is ....... it says for elements with "someclass" attribute open "notOpenedTasks" contextmenu, below code does this...

code below to bind context menu:

```
 $(".someclass").contextMenu( { // binds context menu for these class items
            menu: "notOpenedTasks"  // tells which menu
            //, leftButton: true
        },
        function (action, el, pos) { // any subroutine to call
            contextMenuWork(action, el, pos);
        }
   ).enableContextMenu(); // enables context menu
```

Above code works perfectly..... now the requirement is I should open same contextmenu when user Tabs and gets to that element(Im trying to figureout to open this particular contextmenu when element get focused)....

any ideas....

Comment: Not sure I get it? Are you trying to open the default contextmenu in the browser, if so that can't be done reliably, or is this some sort of plugin ?

Comment: Where did you get the jQuery `.enableContextMenu()` from? It's certainly not a built in function